# How to call function of directive from controller

Tags: angularjs

My directive code is:

```
(function() {
  angular.module('app')
  .directive('dynamicImage', dynamicImage);

  function dynamicImage($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: { dynamic:'&dynamicImage' },
        link: function (scope, elem) {
          scope.dynamic = function(){
          //code here
          }
        }
    };
}
})();
```

My Controller code is : 
In controller How can I call??

```
function theMethodToBeCalled() { 
      $scope.dynamic();
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-12" dynamic-image="theMethodToBeCalled">
    <div class="meet_details_status_img" data-ng-repeat="user in meet.user" data-ng-if="user.extra.invitationStatus === 'pending'">
          <img class="img-circle my-meets-status-img"  ng-src="{{ user.displayPicture ? (imageURL + user.id) : 'assets/images/user_thumb.jpg' }}"
          />
     </div>
</div>
```

Please Help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `expose` an object from `controller` to `directive` and can define a method inside that object in the `directive`. Since you've access to the object which is exposed in directive so you can call any method defined in that `directive`.

**Example -**

```
(function() {
  angular.module('app')
  .directive('dynamicImage', dynamicImage);

  function dynamicImage($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: { dynamic:'&dynamicImage',methodList:'=' },
        link: function (scope, elem) {
          scope.methodList.dynamic = function(){
          //code here
          }
        }
    };
}
})();
```

**In controller -**

```
function CtrlFun($scope){
   $scope.methodList = {};
   $scope.callDirectiveMethod = function(){
      $scope.methodList.dynamic();
   }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div dynamic-image method-list="methodList"> </div>
```

Comment: How to write in HTML?

Comment: By this, I still got errors 'Cannot set property 'dynamic' of undefined'  and '$scope.methodList.dynamic is not a function'

Comment: in html pass method-list="methodList"